# no matching function for call to A::A(MainWindow * const)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, constructor

I do not get rid of the error message 'no matching function for call to A::A(MainWindow * const)' when I try to compile my code. I do not find the problem and greatly appreciate any help!

I have created a gui with qt and try to give a pointer of that to class A in order to access the gui elements from there. My code looks the following:

**mainwindow.h**

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();


private slots:

    void on_cmdStart_clicked();

    void on_cmdAbort_clicked();

...

private:

    A *track; //class A


    QImage qimgOriginal;
    QImage qimgDataBase;
    QTimer* tmrTimer;



//    void run();

};
```

**in mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)  ,
    track(new A(this))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);



}
```

...

**in A.h**

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}                        //without this I receive error: "expected ) before * token"

class A : B/*, public QWidget*/  {

 public:                    

    A(Ui::MainWindow *);
    ~A();
    Ui::MainWindow *GUI;
```

**in A.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"

//i+1 iteration

 A::A(Ui::MainWindow * mainwin) : 
 {
    GUI = mainwin;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of your `A` class takes a `Ui::MainWindow *` and stores that as a member, but your `MainWindow` class is defined in the global namespace, not in `Ui`.

If you want it in that namespace, wrap both the class definition (in the header) and the member definitions in `namespace Ui { ... }` blocks.

If you intend to have it in the global namespace, remove the namespace resolution `Ui::`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this string:

```
track(new A(this))
```

where `this` points to the `MainWindow`, while `A` class expects `Ui::MainWindow` in constructor.

Comment: I also tried MainWindow in the constructor of A, but then I receive an error "expected ) before * token", but I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss a

```
#include "A.h"
```

in the `mainwindow.h` ? Or in the `mainwindow.cpp` while using forward declaration in the header?

Comment: I did #include "A.h" in the mainwindow.h

Answer (score 0):

In your A.cpp file, you define a constructor with a : before its content block, which implies an initialisation list, but don't initialise anything. On my computer (with MSVC) this produces a syntax error.
Is that a typo in your copied code or could it be the reason it's failing? If you're using a different compiler it may give different errors.